# (Tailwind in React) npm run start not working

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I recently started learning Tailwind. I installed tailwind step by step as tailwind website said. After that when I write on VSCode Terminal npm run start.

How to solve this?  Shows some error. What should I do next step to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can create react project with tailwind from strart like this:

1. `npm create vite@latest my-project -- --template react`
2. `cd my-project`
3. `npm install`
4. `npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`
5. `npx tailwindcss init -p`
6. go in tailwind.config.js ==> in content section ==> write like this :
   content: `["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"]`
7. go in index.css file and delete all codes there and write these:
   `@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;`
8. npm run dev